# How do I set up my HTC HD2 to dual boot Windows Mobile and Android?

Tags: htc-hd2

I have read that it is possible to set up the HTC HD2 so that it can dual boot the stock Windows Mobile OS and Android, but I'm not sure where to start. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quickly googled howto/link collection: http://www.htchd2forum.com/android-on-the-hd2/how-to-install-android . Can't really help more without a more specific problem/question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to boot HTC HD2 with Andorid you have 2 possibilities:

1. Use the HTC HD2 Android port that
   boot from a SD card.
2. Reflash the HTC with an Android
   custom ROM

On XDA-Developers you can find extensive information, tutorials and practically any information you can need to accomplish your objective.

- [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=743) you can find the diferent
  forums for each option
- [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=735) is the forum dedicated to
  the SD port
- [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=928) is the forum dedicated to
  the NAND port (needs to reflash your
  phone)